# Хвостовая рекурсия JS

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Доброго времени суток. Не могу понять, почему копятся стеки вызовов функций в хвостовой рекурсии, если результаты предыдущего вызова далее не используются. Например:

```
function foo(x, acc) {
  if (x < 2) {
    return acc;
  }
  return foo(x - 1, acc * x);
}
foo(100000, 1); // Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: а кто-то гарантирует оптимизацию хвостовой рекурсии в javascript?

Comment: да даже если была бы, все равно return нужен на вызов foo в конце

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандарт содержит следующее упоминание

> Tail Position calls are only defined in strict mode code because of a common non-standard language extension ([see 9.2.7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addrestrictedfunctionproperties)) that enables observation of the chain of caller contexts.

---

> Хвостовые вызовы могут быть определены ***только*** в *strict mode*, из-за нестандартного расширения языка ([см 9.2.7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addrestrictedfunctionproperties)), которое позволяет следить за цепочкой вызываемых контекстов.

Таким образом в соответствии со стандартом, хвостая рекурсия в строгом режиме будет обработана правильно.

[Поддерживаемость на данный момент оставляет желать лучшего](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и да, как уже упоминалось: в примере в вопросе не хвостовая рекурсия, для нее нужно добавить `return`, а так же указать `strict mode`, в итоге код должен принять следующий вид

```
function foo(x, acc) {
  'use strict'
  if (x < 2) {
    return acc;
  }
  return foo(x - 1, acc * x);
}
```

Comment: Поясни хоть ты мне, `для нее нужно добавить return` - так в примере ТС оно есть.. Где тут добавлено return?

Comment: Да он поправил уже

Comment: @VladimirGamalian аааа. а то я сижу кукую и не понимаю ответов

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ага, можно просто список редакций глянуть :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто нам нужно было как-то наполнять ответ, вот и делаем вид, что не видели правок )

Answer (score 2):

В `ES5` не обещали, но в `ES6` уже сработает (см. поддержку браузеров в соседнем ответе, если коротко - нет поддержки):

```
function foo(x, acc) {
  "use strict";
  if (x < 2) {
    return acc;
  }
  return foo(x - 1, acc * x);
}

console.log(foo(10000000, 1));
```

(с добавлением `return` к хвостовому вызову `foo`)

Пример рабочий:
http://www.es6fiddle.net/irddgyju/

`babel` превратил этот код в:

```
function foo(_x, _x2) {
  var _again = true;

  _function: while (_again) {
    var x = _x,
        acc = _x2;
    _again = false;

    if (x < 2) {
      return acc;
    }
    _x = x - 1;
    _x2 = acc * x;
    _again = true;
    continue _function;
  }
}
```

По стандарту `"use strict"` обязателен в этом случае, хотя `babel` и без этого пережевал.

Comment: возможно в браузерах либо еще не реализовано, либо не во всех

Comment: @Grundy es6 все равно бабелить перед продакшном, так что наверное ок все

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, во первых не все возможно адекватно "забабелить". Это - нельзя
Во вторых, я стандарт щас прочитал, оптимизация рекурсии strict mode толкьо должно работать.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian я что-то не вижу разницы с примером ТС. почему у него не работает, а тут должно?

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ - tail call optimization. Почти никто не умеет

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tail-position-calls - секция стандарта. Как уже упоминалось tco только в strict mode работает.

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html - ну и наконец статья которая жует стандарт. Если кто-то по ней напишет ответ, будет замечательно

Comment: @Утка может что-то я упустил, почему в этом случае не забабелится tail call?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian открываете первую ссылку с поддержкой es6 фичей, видите что в бабеле tco еще не поддерживается.

Comment: @Утка странненько, мой бабел все сделал как надо, даже без стрикта

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, это вопросы к бабелю, в стандарте действительно написано про _strict mode_, потому что при оптимизации могут сломаться всякие `caller` и `arguments`, кстати, скорее всего с их применением внутри функции бабель должен будет убрать оптимизацию

Comment: @Grundy а, ну про стрикт это да, добавил в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не дам ответ на вопрос, но постараюсь натолкнуть на мысль. Добавьте вывод в консоль `console.log(acc);` после `foo(x - 1, acc * x);` и посмотрите какой будет результат и сколько такой скрипт будет отрабатывать. Уже при `foo(10000, 1);` в консоли вы увидите что `acc = Infinity`, а скрипт будет работать более 2 минут, а при `foo(100000, 1);` Вы получите ошибку "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Comment: Бессмысленный ответ. @Kot и так знает что копится стек. Вопрос был почему js не преобразует рекурисю в цикл (в случае "хвостовой рекурсии" это вполне возможно, и делается во многих языках, автоматически, на уровне компилятора или интерпретатора). Более того, с недавнего времени, это должно поддерживаться и в js.